# Assuming that s is a string of lower case characters. how would i find the number of string y inside s

Tags: python

the following problem in python please .....

Assuming that s is a string of lower case characters.

how would I write a program that prints the number of times the string `'bob'` occurs in `s`. For example, if `s = 'azcbobobegghakl'`, then my program would print

> 'Number of times bob occurs is: 2'

I am a completely new to python and appreciate any help

Comment: Is it just me, or does it look like someone wants us to do his homework?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't want to count overlapping `bob`s as separate values, this would be easy:

```
s.count('bob')
```

But you apparently do. (I had to guess that, based on the fact that your intended output is 2 rather than 1… in the future, it would be better to explain your problem instead of leaving it ambiguous.) As the help says, `count` returns "the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences of substring `sub`…", so that won't do any good.

So, for that, you will have to do it manually. I'll show an example that should have enough to get you started:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:].startswith('bob'):
        print('Found a bob')
```

A slightly smarter way to do this would be to use the `find` method on strings. You can find details on this in the [online docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), or by typing `help(str.find)` in the interactive console. Notice that `find` takes a `start` argument. You should be able to figure out how this would help you; it may take a bit of work to get the details right, but if you get stuck, you can always post a new question asking for specific help.

Comment: ...or use `len(re.findall("(?=(bob))", 'azcbobobegghakl'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
string = "BOBOBOBOBOABCDE"
search = "BOB"
print len([i for i in range(len(string)) if string.startswith(search, i)])
```

Comment: If you're going this way, I'd use `sum(1 for …))`, to avoid building up the filtered list just to take its length. But either way, the odds of the OP being able to understand this code and explain it to his teacher seem pretty slim… which makes it a nice way to trap students who copy and paste answers without thinking, I guess. Or, more usefully, maybe an invitation for students to ask some useful questions.